# AWS Network Load Balancer and TCP traffic with AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I want to expose a tcp-only service from my Fargate cluster to the public internet on port 80. To achieve this I want to use an AWS Network Load Balancer

This is the configuration of my service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "30"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Using the service from inside the cluster with CLUSTER-IP works. When I apply my config with kubectl the following happens:

- Service is created in K8s
- NLB is created in AWS
- NLB gets Status 'active'
- VPC and other values for the NLB look correct
- Target Group is created in AWS
- There are 0 targets registered
- I can't register targets because group expects instances, which I do not have
- EXTERNAL_IP is
- Listener is not created automatically

Then I create a listener for Port 80 and TCP. After some wait an EXTERNAL_IP is assigned to the service in AWS.

My Problem: It does not work. The service is not available using the DNS Name from the NLB and Port 80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *in-tree* Kubernetes `Service` LoadBalancer for AWS, can not be used for AWS Fargate.

> You can use NLB instance targets with pods deployed to nodes, but not to Fargate.

But you can now install [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller) and use **IP Mode** on your `Service` LoadBalancer, this also works for AWS Fargate.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nlb-ip-svc
  annotations:
    # route traffic directly to pod IPs
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb-ip"
```

See [Introducing AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-aws-load-balancer-controller/) and [EKS Network Load Balancer - IP Targets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/load-balancing.html#load-balancer-ip)